# Django deployment https + gunicorn and nginx

Tags: python, django, ssl, nginx, gunicorn

I am stuck with setting the https with django on aws with nginx and gunicorn.

my configuration is:

```
server {
  listen  80;

  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name logitech.enterpriselist.com;
  rewrite ^ https://logitech.enterpriselist.com$request_uri? permanent;
  root /home/ubuntu/git/elist/static/; 
  #`   ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/elist.crt; 
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/elist.key;
  location / {
         #    proxy_pass http://logitech.enterpriselist.com/;
  }
  location /static/ {
      alias /home/ubuntu/git/elist/static/;

  }
}
```

It is working fine with http with port `8001`:

```
 gunicorn configs.wsgi:application --bind 172.31.14.102:8001`
```

and not with domain
`http://logitech.enterpriselist.com:8001/`.

But I also want to run the things with the default port, but when I run

```
gunicorn configs.wsgi:application --bind 172.31.14.102:80
```

it says address already in use!

Also with https when I open `http://logitech.enterpriselist.com/`, it goes to `https://logitech.enterpriselist.com/` but it says website have redirect loop so I need help in sorting this.

Comment: you have other configuration file that included or simlinked with Nginx

Comment: yes i have simlinked the file withing folder sites-enabled one

Comment: I don't use gunicorn but it seems to me that you're asking nginx to listen on port 80 but at the same time you're having gunicorn also listen on the same port. What you want to do is run gunicorn on a high-number port like 8080, then have nginx handle the http request on 80 and proxy to gunicorn in your location block for '/'. Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't got anything to tell nginx it should be proxying requests to gunicorn. In particular, you need a `proxy_pass` directive and an `upstream` section.

Also, you don't want to run gunicorn on port 80, since that is what nginx is already bound to. That's what the proxy is for.

The [gunicorn deployment docs](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/19.3/deploy.html) have an example nginx configuration which works fine.